# How to fix ClickOnce "Value does not fall within the expected range" error occuring at deployment to a non-administrator?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I have looked at several questions on this site and on other sources, but none I found seems to address my situation, despite the same error message.

I've been publishing updates of this particular application with ClickOnce since 3 years ago. The last update before March this year was January last year. Prior to that I had more or less monthly updates and there were never any issues.

As of March, most of the users have no problems, but several of the users are behind a firewall and have a network and system administrators taking care of network and system security among other things. They all now have the same issue described in the following deployment log:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
            Windows                                            : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
            Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
            System.Deployment.dll                              : 4.0.30319.34280 built by: FX452RTMGDR
            clr.dll                                   : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
            dfdll.dll                                              : 4.0.30319.34280 built by: FX452RTMGDR
            dfshim.dll                                          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
            Deployment url                                              : http://doc.pinova.hr/PinovaMeteoUpdates/PinovaSoft/Updates/PinovaSoft.application
                                                                                          Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                                                                                          X-Powered-By  : ASP.NET
            Deployment Provider url                           : http://doc.pinova.hr/PinovaMeteoUpdates/PinovaSoft/Updates/PinovaSoft.application
            Application url                                : http://doc.pinova.hr/PinovaMeteoUpdates/PinovaSoft/Updates/Application%20Files/PinovaSoft_1_5_73_190/PinovaSoft.exe.manifest
                                                                                          Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                                                                                          X-Powered-By  : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
            Deployment Identity                    : PinovaSoft.application, Version=1.5.73.190, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=284eb56ad7414959, processorArchitecture=x86
            Application Identity                      : PinovaSoft.exe, Version=1.5.73.190, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=284eb56ad7414959, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
            * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
            Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
            * Activation of http://doc.pinova.hr/PinovaMeteoUpdates/PinovaSoft/Updates/PinovaSoft.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
                           + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
            No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
            There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:39] : Activation of http://doc.pinova.hr/PinovaMeteoUpdates/PinovaSoft/Updates/PinovaSoft.application has started.
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:39] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:39] : Installation of the application has started.
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:39] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:40] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:40] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
            Following errors were detected during this operation.
            * [16.5.2016. 14:55:40] System.ArgumentException
                           - Value does not fall within the expected range.
                           - Source: System.Deployment
                           - Stack trace:
                                           at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                                           at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
            No transaction information is available.
```

I have spoken to one of the admins in those companies and have found out that even previously, the deployment would not succeed unless the user installing/updating the application had administrator privileges (I was not made aware of this and hence I have no error log from that time). As of March, not even a user with full administrator privilages can install/update the application - only an actual admin can do that.

So, what gives? Can non-administrators install a ClickOnce application *at all* and how?

Comment: This sounds like restrictions on their network as to who can do what. As a click once application it is a network resource and not a local resource therefore depending on their security it will require a domain admin to install the software.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this is helpful, but I'm suspecting malpractice on the side of this particular user. I was unable to help with the ClickOnce deployment, but they agreed it would be OK if I were to send them a package that they could install locally. After having done so, the application worked for a couple of months, and now this same user again has some issues with it. The version he has is still current (there were no updates since then) and no other users have any issues, so I'm suspecting he's tinkering with system files, permissions and such. There are still a few things that I can try.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you why for certain

I saw an MSDN post that says this is 99% caused by a ciruclar reference or references to 2 versions of the same dll.

That kind of fits w/ a new version of a ClickOnce app getting rolled out... i guess...

in any event... this seems to fix the problem for us. I run into it about every 6 months on a single random computer (never systemic...)

rundll32 %wnidir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache

please note that the parameter  CleanOnlineAppCache  is CASE SENSITIVE

(sigh)

hope it helps...